# Conditionally print text or show graph in beamer presentation

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, beamer

I have some difficulties implementing a (`beamer`) presentation. Everything works fine until I include a function which checks a specific condition and accordingly returns the output (graph - print text). Without that function it works fine. So how can I either graph or print the output?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}

<<echo=FALSE, fig.height = 4>>=

  dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-02-13"), as.Date("2015-02-22"), by = "days")
  b <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,0)
  c <- c(20,30,26,20,30,40,5,10,4,0)
  d <- c(11,2233,12,2,22,13,23,23,100,0)
  df <- data.frame(dates,b,c,d)

  plot(df)

  test <- function(df) {
    if(sum(tail(df[2:ncol(df)], 1)) > 0) { # check only last date

      return(plot(df))

    } else {

      print("Have a nice day!")

    }

  }
 test(df)

@

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you have `fig.show='hold'`?

Comment: I think it was because of the arrangment of the plots. But it doent have any effect on the result in the current case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`knitr` wraps output in `verbatim` as can be seen from the TEX that the Rnw in the question produces:

```
\begin{frame}{test}

\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] "Have a nice day!"
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=8cm]{figure/unnamed-chunk-2-1} 

\end{knitrout}

\end{frame}
```

However:

> It is straightforward to use Sweave or `knitr` with beamer; the only thing you need to be careful of is you have to add the `fragile` option to the frames that contain verbatim code. [[Source]](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/beamer/)

Therefore, the frame needs the [`fragile` option](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{test}
```

With `fragile` make sure [not to indent `\end{frame}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234778/indenting-endframe-in-fragile-slides). (This happened to me after copying the code from the question …)

Comment: Thank you. It helps geatly!